# Svelte3 adding <svelte:head> without Sapper?

Tags: server-side-rendering, svelte, sapper, svelte-3

After all day following the google rabbit hole, I’m still wondering about google/bing/etc being able to crawl svelte apps. I want to convert my personal portfolio to svelte, which will be a SPA. If I add  tags for the header data on the svelte SPA, will google pick it up, or do I need ssr for google to see the rendered page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google crawlers will most likely run your JavaScript so that the title etc. inside `<svelte:head>` is picked up, but Bing and others will not.

If you go with Sapper you can use [`sapper export`](https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs#sapper_export) on your site to get a pre-rendered html/svelte hybrid which will solve your issue.

Comment: Be aware that `sapper export` will only *export* file which are linked to via an `<a>` tag: [docs](https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs#How_it_works)

Answer (score 1):

Be aware of using `svelte:head`for your base meta stuff. Things like open graph images or twitter cards will not work this way! This is just useful if you need to inject something to the head on mount, but not safe if you have to deal with SEO.

Comment: what's the fix for SEO?